# ST_INTERSECTS issue BigQuery Waze

Tags: google-bigquery, gis, geography, sqlgeography, waze

I'm using the following code to query a dataset based on a polygon:

```
  SELECT *
FROM `waze-public-dataset.partner_name.view_jams_clustered`
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geo, ST_GEOGFROMTEXT("POLYGON((-99.54913355822276 27.60526592074579,-99.52673174853038 27.60526592074579,-99.52673174853038 27.590813604291416,-99.54913355822276 27.590813604291416,-99.54913355822276 27.60526592074579))")) IS TRUE
```

The validation message says that "This query will process 1 TB when run".

It seems like there's no problem. However, when I remove the "WHERE INTERSECTS" function, the validation message says exactly the same thing: "This query will process 1 TB when run", the same 1 TB, so I'm guessing that the ST_INTERSECTS function is not working.

Comment: in many cases answering extremely simple questions is much much more complex then really complex questions. Let me try - message about processing just simply says houw much data in the table will be processed to get result no matter (with exception for partitioned tables) how and what kind of filtering you want to apply - you still need to process the same amount of data. what is going to be different with and w/o that filter - is amount of data returned as a result of the query. hope this helped

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thank you so much. I got confused because when I filter by a column, this "1 TB" actually changes. So I'm going to run this query to see what happens. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you actually run this query, the amount charged should be usually much less, as expected for spatially clustered table. I've run `select count(*) ...` query with one partner dataset, and while editor UI announced 9TB before running query, the query reported around 150MB processed after running.

The savings come from clustered table - but the specific clusters that intersect the polygon used in filter depend on actual data in the table and how clusters were created. The clusters and thus the cost of the query can only be determined when the query runs. Editor UI in this case shows maximum possible cost of the query.